# Angular JS table creation issue

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I have just started learning Angular JS and I am trying to create an 8X8 table using ng-repeat. I am not able to get 8 table header. All the table header is coming in one column. Here is my code.

```
<table border="1px solid black">
      <tr ng-repeat="k in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">
        <th>
          column
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">
        <td ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">
          [{{i}},{{j}}]
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

This is the output of my code. I am not sure why is that happening.

[image]

Comment: Without knowing angular, you put the `ng-repeat` in the `<tr>` tag, which would logically create 8 rows with a table header in it. Instead try putting the code in the header cell: `<th ng-repeat="k in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]"></th>`

Comment: @SimonBambey Thank you very much. I am new to angular and that is why I made mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ng-repeat` should be in `<th>` not in `<tr>`. If not, you are creating 8 rows with 1 header and you want 1 row with 8 headers.

```
    <table border="1px solid black">
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">
          column
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">
        <td ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]">
          [{{i}},{{j}}]
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: This would create 8 rows of headers with 8 cells each. I believe he is looking for only one header row.

Comment: They say in [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) “using **an** additional `ng-repeat`”. I understand _a/an_ to mean _one_ in this sentence. I could not make it without using _two_ additional `ng-repeat`. It doesn't seem possible with a single one (or I missed some basic point).

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">Column: {{i}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
        <td ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
            [{{i}},{{j}}]
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully...

> ["Extra points: Try and make an 8x8 table using **an additional ng-repeat**..."](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/tutorial/step_02)

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <table>
     <tr><th colspan="8">8x8 Table</th></tr> 
     <tr ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
       <td ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">[{{i+1}},{{j+1}}]</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table>
        <tr>Rows of 8
            <tr ng-repeat="i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">
                <td ng-repeat="a in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">{{i+1}}</td>      
                    <td>{{a}}</td>                      
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
```